# Utilizar un jar en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java

Tengo una duda sobre si se puede llamar un clase que realice en java y utilizar sus métodos en un js ? y en el caso de que se posible como seria ?

Comment: Si la clase es un applet lo podrías hacer, sigue este tutorial : [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html) Aunque el uso de applet ya esta un poco descontinuado, te recomendaria exponer los metodos como un servicio rest, y atravez de peticiones http llamas a los metodos que estas exponiendo : aca un ejemplo paso a paso para que comienzes desde 0 [tutorial rest full](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_first_application.htm)

Comment: Crea una API Rest que ejecute dichos métodos de acuerdo a ciertas rutas y métodos HTTP. En el caso de Node.js, es posible ejecutar el fichero por terminal y capturar la salida, para este propósito puedes usar [tag:bash] o [tag:batch] si estás en MS Windows. También puedes usar RPC usando en RMI en Java.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no lo tengo enfocado a web

Comment: Que no tienes enfocado a la web ? si estas utilizando javaScript es que es una web , no ?

Comment: no, es un daemon de linux

Comment: @BrayanEspinoza ¿Estás usando JavaScript vía Node.js? En ese caso coloca la etiqueta correspondiente.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda